# Find the inner-most text in HTML

Tags: php, html, regex

What would be a regular expression in PHP to find the inner-most text of an HTML string? The tree of the HTML elements has exactly one leave and there can only be a sequence of branches.

Examples where the result is `XXX` (this is not a single string with new-lines; regex would be executed per line):

```
<a>XXX</a>
<a some-attr="bla" some-attr2="bla2"><b>XXX</b></a>
<a>   bla   <b>XXX</b></a>
```

This doesn't need to be assumend:

```
<a>XXX</a><a>XXX</a>
<a><</a>
<a>></a>
```

I would think that is should be something like `>(.*?)<` but all characters before and behind would have to be ignored.

---

Updated to allow an enhanced answer of Wiktor Stribiżew:
An additional task is to **replace the found string** with PHP by another. This might lead to another pattern as it would be with just finding and getting the inner-most string - not sure.

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse context-free language (such as HTML) is nonsensical. Use [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: @JiriHrazdil This is not parsing html, this is simply fetching a part of html from the greater context. The  task only cares whether there seems to be an inner element or not, but does not attempt to read the tags, balance them, render them or otherwise use them for lookup. Parsing != finding.

Comment: @melwil: OP wants to find the _inner-most text_. Even though the word _find_ is used, the _inner-most_ part refers to the structure (_tree of HTML elements_), which implies parsing.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Actually, I'd like to replace this string. However, I see now that I also don't know how to accomplish this with php. [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) does not work with the pattern. But using `'>YYY<'` as $replacement seems to be okay.

Comment: What is the final result you want to obtain for the HTML fragment above?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil We could argue forever on this, but just tossing about links and hate about regex and parsing is silly in itself. Most cases where people wish to do things like OP here, they are working with procedurally generated code anyway. You may link the warnings if you want, but no solution is the wrong solution every time. Regex is a powerful tool, and wanting to learn to use it makes a ton of sense. I agree that hunger for learning should be tempered with knowledge on the best practices of use, but don't just push a solution away because "that's what SO agrees is the best".

Comment: @melwil You're right. From my view I mainly see a string that I'd like to manipulate (or where I'd like to find a certain piece). If there would be more to do I would considering about using a DOM parser. But here the regex seems to be sufficient and probably even faster. I see regex as a common and useful tool, and I prefer it also since the knowledge about it can be used in many languages. The DOM parser is probably a certain implementation in PHP. This knowledge cannot be used when one is also a JAVA programmer. So, long live the regex!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Finally, I'd like to replace the most-inner part with another string (PHP). But my post and the answers that followed are only about capturing this string. Because of the answers I won't change the question anymore.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/jJcGDD, is it the thing you are looking for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I think that solves my problem completely! Thanks. I've updated my question so you can provide an official, upvotable answer - if you'd like to do so. Thank you too, Maverick_Mrt and Anton, for you answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to know about the issues that you may experience when using regex with HTML, so please take the regex answer as a learning excercise and use DOM parsing in production *if you have to use it with arbitrary HTML code*.

IMHO, *if you know what you are doing*, that is, you are in full control of the generated HTML and you know all `<` are serialized as HTML entities and all tags consist of alphanumeric/underscore chars, you may use a regex for this:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<a>XXX</a>
<a some-attr="bla" some-attr2="bla2"><b>XXX</b></a>
<a>   bla   <b>XXX</b></a>
DATA;
echo preg_replace('~(<(\w+)[^<]*?>)[^<]*(<\/\2>)~', '$1YYY$3', $html);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/jJcGDD) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S4vAkk/1).

The result is all text inside tags with no tags inside gets replace with `YYY`:

```
<a>YYY</a>
<a some-attr="bla" some-attr2="bla2"><b>YYY</b></a>
<a>   bla   <b>YYY</b></a>
```

**Details**:

- `(<(\w+)[^<]*?>)` - Group 1 capturing `<`, then capturing into Group 2 (a technical group for us to be able to match the same tag name in the closing tag)1 or more word chars, then any 0+ chars other than `<` as few as possible (with a negated character class `[^<]` and the lazy quantifier `*?`)
- `[^<]*` - the text contents: zero or more characters other than `<`, as many as possible
- `(<\/\2>)` - Group 3: `<`, `/`, the same text as in Group 2 (the tag name) and a `>`.

In the replacement, we just use `$1` and `$3` backreferences to Group 1 and 3 to reinsert the text captured into those groups, and add the `YYY` replacement text.

Comment: Thanks. This even works for all leaves! And I swear, so help me god, I will consider using a DOM parser if things getting more complex ;-)

Comment: As I mentioned, use DOM obligatorily with *arbitrary* HTML you have no control of.

Answer (score 2):

You might use something like this

```
>([^><]+)<\/
```

It will match everything between `>` `</` which is not `>` or `<`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/3VmRQJ/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>((?:(?!<).)+?)<\/
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/3VmRQJ/2)

Tried On:

```
<a>XXX1</a>
<a some-attr="bla" some-attr2="bla2"><b>XXX2</b></a>
<a>   bla   <b>XXX3</b></a>
```

And capture group for each line contains:

```
XXX1
XXX2
XXX3
```

Comment: @maverick-mrt would it be possible to just use `>([^><]+)<\/`  in this case?